# SQL Query to Join Two Tables Based Off Closest Timestamp

Tags: sql, timestamp, left-join

I have two tables in SQL and I need to be able to do a join based off of the timestamp in table B that is earlier than or equal to the timestamp in table A.

So, here is some fake data for two tables and the desired output:

**Closed Cases (Table A)**

```
| id | resolution |         timestamp          |
------------------------------------------------
|  1 |     solved | 2006-10-05 11:55:44.888153 |
|  2 |     closed | 2007-10-07 12:34:17.033498 |
|  3 |    trashed | 2008-10-09 08:19:36.983747 |
|  4 |     solved | 2010-10-13 04:28:14.348753 |
```

**Classification (Table B)**

```
| id |    value    |         timestamp          |
-------------------------------------------------
|  1 |    freshman | 2006-01-01 12:02:44.888153 |
|  2 |   sophomore | 2007-01-01 12:01:19.984333 |
|  3 |      junior | 2008-01-01 12:02:28.746149 |
```

**Desired Results**

```
| id | resolution |         timestamp          |    value    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |     solved | 2006-10-05 11:55:44.888153 |    freshman |
|  2 |     closed | 2007-10-07 12:34:17.033498 |   sophomore |
|  3 |    trashed | 2008-10-09 08:19:36.983747 |      junior |
|  4 |     solved | 2010-10-13 04:28:14.348753 |      junior |
```

So, I know the code needs to look like the following, I just can't figure out what to do with the `ON` portion of the `JOIN` ($1 and $2 are variables that will be passed in):

```
SELECT case.id, case.resolution, case.timestamp, class.value
  FROM closed_cases AS case
  LEFT JOIN classifications AS class ON ???
  WHERE case.timestamp BETWEEN $1 AND $2;
```

I know I could use a sub-select, but this will be operating on at least a few thousand rows, probably more, and I need it to be really fast; so I was hoping for a simple clause that could do it.

Comment: I think you'll need your sub-select.  Have you tested the performance and found it unacceptable?

Comment: if the version of SQL you're using supports windowing analytical functions you should be able to do it without a sub-select, but some versions of SQL don't support them. For a single sub-select on a few thousand rows, performance shouldn't be too bad. (The sub-select will be on the classification table - will this really have more than a few thousand rows?)

Comment: @Mark - Actually, come to think of it, the classification table should have way less rows than that as I'll be checking to see if the data has actually changed from the most current version. So I guess the sub-select would have worked just fine, but I think adding the end time is a far cleaner solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you can make changes to the table structures, I recommend changing the classification table to include an end date as well as a start date - it will be much easier to join to the table that way.

If not, I suggest the following:

```
SELECT case.id, case.resolution, case.timestamp, class.value
  FROM closed_cases AS case
  LEFT JOIN (select c.*, 
                    (select min(timestamp)
                     from classifications c1
                      where c1.timestamp > c.timestamp) timeend
             from classifications c) AS class 
  ON case.timestamp >= class.timestamp and 
     (case.timestamp < class.timeend or class.timeend IS NULL)
  WHERE case.timestamp BETWEEN $1 AND $2;
```

EDIT - with the end date on classification:

```
SELECT case.id, case.resolution, case.timestamp, class.value
  FROM closed_cases AS case
  LEFT JOIN classifications AS class 
  ON case.timestamp >= class.timestamp and case.timestamp < class.timeend
  WHERE case.timestamp BETWEEN $1 AND $2;
```

Comment: Can you explain briefly how changing the table structure to include the end date would help? I could theoretically do this by always setting the current end date to be some time really far in the future and updating the previous entry's end date to be the current entries start date.

Comment: @Topher - additional query added; no sub-select is required, and the query should be sargable.

Comment: `select min(timestamp)
                     from classifications c1
                      where c1.timestamp > c.timestamp`   < does this really work? The c table is not specified.

Answer (score 1):

In if your SQL has window functions, so probably versions 8 and higher, the easiest way to do that is to use [LEAD function](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lead-function/) on classification timestamp, effectively achieving simpler @user359040's solution

Comment: To clarify: If it is impossible to add a `timeend` column to the underlying table, we can compute it on the fly via `LEAD(timestamp) over (order by timestamp asc) as timeend` [or similar depending on your dialect]. If `lead` is also not available we can fall back to the self-join approach from @user359040.

Answer (score 0):

change the time stamp and use an int as a key to connect the tables. this will work much faster then comparing date

table 1
field1
field2
field3
ConnectorField

table2 
field1
field2
field3
ConnectorField

and all you need to do is
select * from table1 T1 inner join table2 T2 on T1.ConnectorField = T2.ConnectorField

Comment: This solution requires that the OP can change the structure of the existing database, and will prevent changes to the date ranges of classifications against existing cases.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether or not I use an integer (aren't timestamps stored as integers anyway), this still doesn't solve the problem of "closest to". I would still need to do the join based off of exactly one integer in table B that is less than or equal to the integer in table A.

Comment: @Topher, probably i didn't understand the specification.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT case.id, case.resolution, case.timestamp, class.value
  FROM closed_cases AS case
  LEFT JOIN classifications AS class 
  ON case.timestamp >= class.timestamp
  WHERE case.timestamp BETWEEN $1 AND $2;
```

Comment: This will return all classifications after the case timestamp for each case, instead of just the applicable classification - so for the example provided, you would see 11 rows returned instead of the 4 required.

Comment: @Mark Mannister - Exactly. I need only the 4 rows (I'm going to do a count and group them later).