# Merging two data sets on closest date efficiently in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, algorithm, postgresql, merge, greatest-n-per-group

I try to merge two tables with different time resolution on their closest date.

The tables are like this:

Table1:

```
id    | date    | device  | value1
----------------------------------
1     | 10:22   | 13      | 0.53
2     | 10:24   | 13      | 0.67
3     | 10:25   | 14      | 0.83
4     | 10:25   | 13      | 0.32
```

Table2:

```
id    | date    | device  | value2
----------------------------------
22    | 10:18   | 13      | 0.77
23    | 10:21   | 14      | 0.53
24    | 10:23   | 13      | 0.67
25    | 10:28   | 14      | 0.83
26    | 10:31   | 13      | 0.23
```

I want to merge these tables along the first one. So I want to append value2 to Table1, where, for each device, the latest value2 appears.

Result:

```
id    | date    | device  | value1 | value2
-------------------------------------------
1     | 10:22   | 13      | 0.53   | 0.77
2     | 10:24   | 13      | 0.67   | 0.67
3     | 10:25   | 14      | 0.83   | 0.53
4     | 10:25   | 13      | 0.32   | 0.67
```

I have some (20-30) devices, thousands of rows in Table2 (=m) and millions of them in Table1 (=n).

I could sort all the tables along date (`O(n*logn)`), write them into a text file and iterate over Table1 like a merge, while pulling data from Table2 until it is newer (I have to manage that ~20-30 pointers to the latest data for each device, but no more), and after the merge I could upload it back to the database. Then the complexities are `O(n*log(n))` for sorting and `O(n+m)` for iterating over the tables.

But it would be much better to do it in the database at all. But the best query I could achive was O(n^2) complexity:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Table1.id)
       Table1.id, Table1.date, Table1.device, Table1.value1, Table2.value2
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.date > Table2.date and Table1.device = Table2.device
ORDER BY Table1.id, Table1.date-Table2.date;
```

It's really slow for the data amount I need to process, are there better ways to do this? Or just do that stuff with the downloaded data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query to Join Two Tables Based Off Closest Timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070476/sql-query-to-join-two-tables-based-off-closest-timestamp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because table 1 is so much smaller, it might be more efficient to use a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.value2
        from table2 t2
        where t2.device = t.device and t2.date <= t1.date
        order by t2.date desc
        limit 1
       ) as value2
from table1 t1;
```

Also create an index on `table2(device, date, value2)` for performance.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong: Table2 is the smaller, Table1 is the larger, so values from Table2 will be in the Result table multiple times (as in the example). I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @hunyadym . . . The same idea should hold.  The index for `table1` should easily fit into memory and each row in table2 will require a short scan of this index.

Comment: Great, I tried it out and it's much more faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Your query can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t1.id)
       t1.id, t1.date, t1.device, t1.value1, t2.value2
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   table2 t2 USING (device)
WHERE  t1.date > t2.date
ORDER  BY t1.id, t2.date DESC;
```

No need to calculate a date difference for every combination of rows (which is expensive and not [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)), just pick the row with the greatest `t2.date` from each set. Index support is advisable.
Details for `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

That's probably not fast enough, yet. Given your data distribution you would need a *loose index scan*, which can be emulated with correlated subqueries (like Gordon's query) or a more modern and versatile `JOIN LATERAL`:

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.date, t1.device, t1.value1, t2.value2
FROM   table1 t1
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT value2
   FROM   table2
   WHERE  device = t1.device
   AND    date   < t1.date
   ORDER  BY date DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) t2 ON TRUE;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` avoids losing rows when no match is found in `t2`. Details:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

But that's ***still not very fast***, since you have *"thousands of rows in Table2 and millions of them in Table1"*.

Two ideas, probably faster, but also more complex:

#### 1. `UNION ALL` plus window functions

Combine `Table1` and `Table2` in a `UNION ALL` query and run a window function over the derived table. This is enhanced by the [**"moving aggregate support" in Postgres 9.4**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.4#Moving-aggregate_support) or later.

```sql
SELECT id, date, device, value1, value2
FROM  (
   SELECT id, date, device, value1
        , min(value2) OVER (PARTITION BY device, grp) AS value2
   FROM  (
      SELECT *
           , count(value2) OVER (PARTITION BY device ORDER BY date) AS grp
      FROM  (
         SELECT id, date, device, value1, NULL::numeric AS value2 
         FROM   table1

         UNION  ALL
         SELECT id, date, device, NULL::numeric AS value1, value2
         FROM   table2
         ) s1
      ) s2
   ) s3
WHERE  value1 IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY date, id;
```

You'll have to test if it can compete. Sufficient [`work_mem`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM) allows in-memory sorting.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b3b2a7a5d24d4e00ac1a31dff78f985a)* for all three queries
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/295f2/1)</sub>

#### 2. PL/pgSQL function

Cursor for each device in `Table2`, loop over `Table1`, pick the value from respective device-cursor after advancing until `cursor.date > t1.date` and keeping `value2` from the row before last. Similar to the winning implementation here:

- [Window Functions or Common Table Expressions: count previous rows within range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173412/window-functions-or-common-table-expressions-generate-a-count-of-previous-recor/18174102#18174102)

Probably fastest, but more code to write.

Comment: Way to knock this out of the park!  You should have gotten the best answer.