# How to find the closest value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How to determine the RESULTS field in table users, base on USER SCORE field with the provisions of the value closest to SCORE BRAND field.

[image]

This is table Brand

```
    <table>
<tr>
<th>BRAND NAME</th>
<th>SCORE BRAND</th>
</tr>";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brand");
while($m=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
echo "<tr> 
<td>$m[brand_name]</td>
<td>$m[score]</td><tr>";
}
</table>
```

This is table users

```
    <table>
<tr>
<th>USER NAME</th>
<th>SCORE USER</th>
<th>RESULT</th>
</tr>";
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($u=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){ 
echo "<tr> 
<td>$u[username]</td>
<td>$u[score]</td>
<td> ??? </td>
<tr>";
}
</table>
```

Comment: What if user has a score of `55` - what is the desired result? `Axa` or `Autocilin`?

Comment: im just try with if else condition, but not working. 55 should be autocilin.

Comment: What version of `MySQL` are you using, is it `> 5.7.6` ?

Comment: @SigitPrasetya, Please check my answer..

Comment: Hope this will provide help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070476/sql-query-to-join-two-tables-based-off-closest-timestamp

Comment: **The `mysql` PHP extension is dead** -- Stop using the [`mysql` PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). It is old, deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use subquery in selection to find proper brand for every selected user like this:

```
SELECT u.*, (
    SELECT b.id
    FROM brand AS b
    ORDER BY ABS(b.score - u.score) ASC, b.score DESC -- selects brands ordered by their difference from user's score
    LIMIT 1 -- get just the first brand (with score closest to user's)
)
FROM user AS u
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from table 
order by abs(value - $myvalue)
limit 1
```

Comment: Can you describe the variable $myvalue ?

Comment: $myvalue would be the score that you are looking up against - this would result in 1 query per brand - Roman Hocke's answer does the same thing but in 1 overall query

Answer (score 0):

You should have some pre-defined threshold to match around (so that score 1 would not match with score 1000).

```
SELECT .. WHERE score_brand >= score_user - :epsilon AND score_brand <= score_user + :epsilon
```

Comment: there is no predefined threshold, its like diagnosis statement base on brand

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got some pretty solution:

```
SELECT u.*, b.nama_lengkap as result 
FROM `users` AS u 
JOIN `brands` AS b 
WHERE (b.score - u.score) > 0 
AND (b.score - u.score) < 10 
ORDER BY u.id;
```

*b.nama_lengkap -> brand name*

I have just joined two tables and did some arithmetic operation to get the appropriate row.

**EDIT**

```
SELECT v.id, v.username, v.score, b.nama_lengkap AS result
FROM (SELECT users.id, users.score, users.username, min(brands.score) nextSc
      FROM users
      LEFT JOIN brands
        ON users.score <= brands.score
     GROUP BY users.id, users.score) AS v
LEFT JOIN brands b
  ON v.nextSc = b.score
ORDER BY v.id, v.score;
```

This is the complete dynamic query for any multiplicated values. It will get you closure score of brands for users.

You can find [LIVE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6d3c/1)

Comment: @SigitPrasetya, What happened? did my query not work?

Comment: it's work... But only for multiples of 10. How about multiples 2,3,...,and greater than 10

Comment: @SigitPrasetya, I have updated my answer with Demo. Hope this one is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hey, @SigitPrasetya, Isn't this update working for you?